# Python: How to group dictionaries based on a key value pair

Tags: python, mysql, database, list, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries in Python containing audio metadata in this format:

```
metadata = {'title': meta['title'][0],
            'artist': meta['artist'][0],
            'album': meta['album'][0],
            'path': path}
```

Is there any way to iterate over a list of these dictionaries, concatenate unique `artist` fields into a single `artists` field, based on the `album` field, but keep one of the paths?

For example, turning these dictionaries:

```
m1 = {'title': 'Song 1', 'artist': 'Artist 1', 'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 1'}
m2 = {'title': 'Song 2', 'artist': 'Artist 1 Ft 2', 'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 2'}
m3 = {'title': 'Song 3', 'artist': 'Artist 1 Ft 3', 'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 3'}
```

Into this:

```
m4 = {'artist': 'Artist 1; Artist 1 Ft 2; Artist 1 Ft 3', 'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 1'}
```

The reasoning behind this is I want to create a list of albums and their artists from a list of files (represented by the dictionaries), but I need to keep one of the paths to get album artwork from.

So far, I've tried adding all the data to a MySQL database, with a BLOB of the album artwork in an `image` column, and running the SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE albums SELECT album, image, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT artist SEPARATOR '; ') AS artists FROM tracks GROUP BY album
```

and then dropping the image column from the main database of tracks, however this is really resource intensive and takes up a lot of unnecessary space in the database while building it, so ideally I need some way of doing this with the raw data in Python first.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, in the list of dictionaries, there will be multiple albums. I need the end result to be a list of dictionaries each containing a unique album and a concatenated list of all the artist tags corresponding to that album.

Comment: There is a way.. For those who think. Hang on

Comment: What about the titles?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't need those, all the track titles are kept in a database, I can look the title up using the album title.

Comment: Well, if a different album shows up? What would the end result be like?

Comment: @alKid I want to create a list of all unique albums with a concatenated list of artists, there will be multiple albums. I'll edit my question to include it, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: @CallumBooth I expected that.. My answer will work even if you have multiple albums :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = [
    {'title': 'Song 1', 'artist': 'Artist 1',
        'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 1'},
    {'title': 'Song 2', 'artist': 'Artist 1 Ft 2',
        'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 2'},
    {'title': 'Song 3', 'artist': 'Artist 1 Ft 3',
        'Album': 'Album 1', 'Path': 'path 3'}
]

from collections import defaultdict

# Group all the artists, as per the Album name
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in m:
    d[item["Album"]].append(item["artist"])

# Gather paths corresponding to the Albums
p = {item["Album"]: item["Path"] for item in m}

# Recreate a list of all albums with artist names joined
result = []
for album in d:
    result.append({
        "Album" : album,
        "artist": "; ".join(d[album]),
        "Path"  : p[album]
    })

print result
```

Comment: I must have gotten dull.. Good answer!